# Mostrar propiedades de un array JSON

Tags: json, twig

estoy intentando acceder a la propiedad "documento" del siguiente objeto JSON en Twig:

```
"resultados":[
{
"index":"ldi",
"id":"2ms2TX4Bdk30_Q6uvs-B",
"score":95,
"fuente":"B_PEPS_SI_AR",
"tipoFuente":"PEP",
"descripcionFuente":"PEPS de Argentina sin identificación",
"sdnId":"5806203",
"fechaNovedad":null,
"nombre":"GARCIA IGNACIO",
"documento":null,
"identificacionTributaria":null,
"institucion":"HONORABLE CONCEJO DELIBERANTE DE GENERAL VILLEGAS",
"cargo":"Concejal",
"relacion":null,
"domicilio":"Buenos Aires Ar",
"residencia":"AR",
"descripcionPais":"Argentina",
"url":"http://link2.pld.global/verdetallelistas.asp?cod=eb06ebdcda79e18a10fafd98daf66a78",
"evaluacion":2,
"existeDocumentacion":false
},
{
"index":"ldi",
"id":"tXI3TX4Bdk30_Q6u2HAM",
"score":95,
"fuente":"B_PEPS_CI_AR",
"tipoFuente":"PEP",
"descripcionFuente":"PEPS de Argentina con identificación",
"sdnId":"14355577",
"fechaNovedad":"2020-12-03T00:00:00",
"nombre":"IGNACIO GARCIA",
"documento":"25021747",
"identificacionTributaria":"20250217472",
"institucion":"SCRAPSERVICE SOC ANONIMA",
"cargo":"AUTORIDAD",
"relacion":"GOLLAN CARLOS ALBERTO (DNI 16885661)",
"domicilio":"AV.DE LOS CONSTITUYENTES 4175 - DON TORCUATO - BUENOS AIRES",
"residencia":"AR",
"descripcionPais":"Argentina",
"url":"http://info.pld.global/Base/Index?referencia=Ql9QRVBTX0NJX0FSfDE0MzU1NTc3",
"evaluacion":2,
"existeDocumentacion":false
}
]
```

Intenté con ${resultados.documento} y ${resultados[8]} pero ninguna funciona. ¿Cómo podría hacer para acceder al valor de dicha propiedad? Agradezco la ayuda de antemano!

PD: La información publicada es de dominio público.

Comment: Si observas, tu JSON es un array, entonces, debes indicar el índice del elemento cuyos datos quieres obtener, sabiendo que los indices empiezan por `0`. Así, para el primer elemento: `${resultados[0].documento}`  y para el segundo: `${resultados[1].documento}` ... etc ...

Comment: Genial!, y en el caso de querer traer el documento de todos los objetos dentro del array como sería? @A.Cedano

Comment: puedes recorrer ese json con un for en el twig, e ir recogiendo cada 'documento'

Comment: Al ser un array, lo puedes recorrer dentro de un bucle.

Comment: No uso Twing, pero [sería algo como esto supongo](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable): `{% for data in resultados %}
    {{ data.documento }}
{% endfor %}`  asumiendo que tu objeto JSON se llama  `resultados`. Y si te interesa mostrar las llaves : valores de cada elemento, [algo como esto más o menos](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#iterating-over-keys-and-values). En fin, leer la documentación siempre, donde está casi todo explicado.

Comment: Gracias! fueron de gran ayuda